# Google App Engine's 1 minute cron limitation

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using GAE Java for my web application and I need to run a scheduled task every 30 seconds. However, I know that the minimum is 1 minute. Any ideas (and possibly working example ) of how to do that? I've read that you can use Task Queues instead, but couldn't find how to schedule queue tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "schedule tasks" by specifying when they should run. They have a parameter that tells it the delay to wait so you create 2 task queues one runs "now" (delay 0) and the other runs with 30sec delay. See the countdown property.https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks#countdown_arg
 You can then have the 1minute cron do that.
However, the frontend will never sleep plus you will consume more with the task queues. You can also use a single backend and have it run 2 threads or your own scheduler in a loop. Keep a cron to restart the backend if it goes down (which will after about 15min)